# grails 2.2.2 Error executing script RunApp: class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44 cannot access its superclass sun.reflect.MethodAccessorImpl

Tags: grails

I have facing the issue about grails 2.2.2. 
My application is running well, but after I re-setup my PC, and re-installed the softwares, like: JDK, GGTS... I always get the following error when I run command:

```
grails run-app
```

errors:

```
| Configuring classpath
Resolving [test] dependencies...
Resolving [runtime] dependencies...
| Error Error executing script RunApp: class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44 cannot access its superclass sun.reflect.MethodAccessorImpl
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44 cannot access its superclass sun.reflect.MethodAccessorImpl
at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:396)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateMethod(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.ClasspathConfigurer.addUrlsToRootLoader(ClasspathConfigurer.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.ClasspathConfigurer.configuredClassLoader(ClasspathConfigurer.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.initializeState(GrailsScriptRunner.java:624)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.callPluginOrGrailsScript(GrailsScriptRunner.java:408)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:373)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:232)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1243)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
| Error Error executing script RunApp: class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44 cannot access its superclass sun.reflect.MethodAccessorImpl
```

In fact, the error arose not just when run command: `grails run-app`, even when run command: `grails --refresh-dependencies`

Here is the similar error:

```
 Error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 Error         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 Error         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
 Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
 Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 Error         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 Error         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
 Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)
 Error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41 cannot access its superclass sun.reflect.MethodAccessorImpl
 Error         at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
 Error         at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:63)
 Error         at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
 Error         at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:396)
 Error         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 Error         at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:395)
 Error         at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateMethod(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:77)
 Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:46)
 Error         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 Error         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
 Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.ClasspathConfigurer.addUrlsToRootLoader(ClasspathConfigurer.java:280)
 Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.ClasspathConfigurer.configuredClassLoader(ClasspathConfigurer.java:74)
 Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.initializeState(GrailsScriptRunner.java:624)
 Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.initializeState(GrailsScriptRunner.java:607)
 Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:220)
 Error         ... 12 more
```

Dose anyone have some ideas about this issue?

Note: I tried in two JDK version: 1.6.0_29 and 1.7.0_11, get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is the configuration error of classpath: I configured the rt.jar library of jre in the classpath. Remove it, then fix this issue.